# How to drop idle connections in CloudSQL(Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

We have an issue with too many open connections in our staging DB Postgresql instance hosted on CloudSQL.

I would like to know if there is any workaround for `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` command on CloudSQL. In order to be able to run this command, we would need to have superuser access which is unfortunately not the case for [CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/features#differences-pg).

I would like to avoid setting up a batch job which would remove idle connections periodically. Can you think of a better alternative?

Comment: Some of these settings can be set for database for which you do not need superuser. We for example set work_mem on CloudSQL this way. See ALTER DATABASE .... SET config_param - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-alterdatabase.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` could be set on a db level. See example [here](https://blog.dbi-services.com/a-look-at-postgresql-9-6-killing-idle-transactions-automatically/)

Comment: @user2548047 Have you found a solution for this? 
I'm not sure, but cloud sql proxy seems to be creating a lot of idle connections...

Answer (score 2):

You can set `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` on a db level, but it's going to last one session, so that's not a good approach. Instead of using `alter system` you can just use `set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`.

If you do need this flexibility, what you can do as a workaround is create a Compute Engine instance and use your postgreSQL form there, having full access.